# jquery .index() function returning incorrect

Tags: jquery

The `.index()` function is not returning the correct index for me unless I have the whole concept of index() wrong :)

**so this is the logic behind it**

```
<div class="sections">Section 1</div>
<div class="sections">Section 2</div>
<div class="sections">Section 3</div>
<div class="sections">Section 4</div>

.sections{display:none;} //css 

$('.sections:eq(1)').show();// shows sectiond 2 text
$('.sections:visible').index();// returns 2 I expected 1
```

**Actual website**

```
<div class="sections">Section 1</div>
var section = $('.sections:visible').index();// returns 2
console.log($('.sections:visible').length); // returns 1
console.log($('.sections').length); // returns 1 as well since there is one section
window.location.hash = 'section-'+section;// url hash is #section-2
```

Comment: It's returning `1` for me on Chrome using http://jsfiddle.net/DsSV5/

Comment: well return 1 for me http://jsfiddle.net/AbEWF/1/

Comment: same with me on jsfiddle. on my actual site I only have one `.section` div but to demonstrate it better here i put multiples. I don't know where that two is coming from ... I used the .length aswell returns one which means there aren't any other divs of the same class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading through the `.index()` http://api.jquery.com/index/ properly I had discovered that if you specify the list as an attribute it will fix the problem.

e.g.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div>First Page</div>
  <div class="sections">Section 1</div>
  <div class="sections">Section 2</div>
  <div class="sections">Section 3</div>
  <div class="sections">Section 4</div>
  </div>Last Page</div>
</div>
```

using simply `$('.sections:visible').index();` would return incorrect result as `first page` and `last page are also included on the list (which is what I had).`

so to fix this problem I had to do the following.

```
$('.sections:visible').index($('.sections'));
```

in other word we are saying find the index of  `:visible` from the list of `$('.selections')`

hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed something up. The index 1 in an array means the second element of whole collection. The selectors of jquery return always an array.

Look at [Visual Jquery](http://visualjquery.com/) for '.eq()'

Comment: lol I know we should have a silly-meter here so people know our level of understanding :)

Comment: If you look up the example of .eq() then you will find out what I meant. All three examples marked in fact the third element.

Comment: yes I know its indexed which means it starts from 0 and not 1, so the .index() function therefore is indexed 0 based too should return 1 in logic but it doesnt see updated question

Comment: you should check http://api.jquery.com/index/ I think coz ur underestimating my scripting knowledge lol :) no offence btw but u do have a point

Comment: Yeah I see it now. So I have to apologize.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sections:visible').index($('.sections'));
```

in other word we are saying find the index of  :visible from the list of  `$('.selections')`

Without argument it gives the index of the selector. With argument it works the other way around. As `.sections` is not part of `.sections:visible` it gives -1 (not found).

So the right answer is :

```
$('.sections').index($('.sections:visible'));
```